# Can't remove vysor language updates from `apt-get update`

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I have removed the package vysor in every possible way on ubuntu using

- `sudo apt-get remove vysor`
- `sudo apt-get purge vysor`  and `sudo apt-get --purge vysor` and `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`
- `sudo snap remove vysor`
- I see nothing after `dpkg --list | grep vysor*`
  but whenever I run `sudo apt-get update` the languages updates with `Ign:23 https://nuts.vysor.io/apt ./ Translation-en`   always wastes my 10 seconds.

[image]

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Remove the package from `/etc/apt/sources.list` or from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, and try again.

Comment: done, there were no vysor related lines, but no success.

Comment: Did you install it like it says on the website, with `(echo 'deb [arch=amd64, trusted=yes] https://nuts.vysor.io/apt ./' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vysor.list) && sudo apt update && sudo apt install vysor`? In that case there should be a `vysor.list` file though.

Comment: Great, @Jos, I have removed that list and it is gone now. You can write this comment as answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installation instructions on the website [vysor.io](https://vysor.io) cause a `vysor.list` file to be added in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. The list file contains a link to the `vysor` repository. Although you have removed the package itself, the `.list` file is still there and will be consulted by `apt` every time you look for updates. Of course, no relevant update is found.

The way to avoid the `.list` file being read is to remove it. Another way would be to rename it to something like `vysor.link.backup` in case you change your mind, as only files with the `.list` extension are read.

Sensible `uninstall` instructions would include this bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

yeah jos is right thank you jos.i am beginner with low reputation. so i am adding this comment
locate the list file and remove it.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vysor.list
```

hope so vysor will not bother any more